# Sending messages to objects created in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, object, methods, interface-builder

I'm quite new to Cocoa, Objective-C and OOP in general. I'm learning every day. According to 'Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X for DUMmIES' you can create an object in Xcode like this:

`myObject = [[Class_name alloc] init];`

Afterwards you'll be able to send it messages according to the methods decladed in `Class_name`. So far so good. But yesterday I followed this tutorial: [Intro to Bindings](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000080.php) and noticed something weird. According to the tutorial, you mustcreate an NSArrayController object within Interface Builder. But if you want to add a row to the array, managed by the controller, with values from let's say a couple of NSTextFields, you need to call it's AddObject method, but how? I don't know the objects name or identifier, right?

Answer (score 0):

Simply create an outlet

```
IBOutlet NSArrayController *arrayController;
```

and connect your `arrayController` to it in IB;
To call its method use `[arrayController methodName];`

Comment: Yeah I know, but I want to do it from code. Because in this way (calling the Add: method) I get an empty row in my array. And I want to fill it with the contents of a couple of TextFields, or am I missing something?

Comment: If i am right, your your collection view(or something) which is binded to the array controller doesnt update its content. If thats so, read KVO guide [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/KeyValueObserving_QuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Eh, no that's not exactly what's happening. I need to add a row to the array. Apparently, the way to do this is by calling the addObject method of the array controller. The array controller updates the tableView automatically. But how do I call this method from code? I can do it in Interface Builder, but then only an empty row is added. And I want to use a sheet where you can type some thing and use those values for the new row.

Comment: Some where in your controller class add this method: 
`- (IBAction)addDataRow
{
[arrayController addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[textField1 stringValue],@"name",[textField2 stringValue],@"description", nil]];
[tableView reloadData];
}`
Connect this action to any button in IB. And check your column's `Model Key Path` values. They must be the same as keys in the dictionary.